# I need help migrating a SharePoint 3.0 server from domain a to domain b. Domain b users cannot access the content

Tags: migration, wss-3.0

I wonder if you can help me please.  I have a SharePoint 3.0 instance on a dedicated server (not running AD), and I have migrated that server over to a new network (from Domain A to Domain B) over the weekend.

Previously only users for Domain A were authorised to access the content of the SharePoint site, but I need to authorise users from Domain B to have access to that content moving forward.

I have tried using the stsadm.exe -o migrateuser command, but it says the user does not exist or is not unique.  I have created user accounts in AD on the new domain controller for all our staff.

Factors that may be relevant - I have re-connected the server back onto the old domain in the hopes that I could explicitly authorise those users, but the SharePoint instance's People Picker only seems able to produce a list of those users in Domain A, which is no use to me.  I attempted to do the same whilst the server was between domains, but it could not draw off a list of users from either domain.

I am really stuck, and do not know what else to do - can anybody offer any help ?

Thanks so much.

Comment: What are the SID values for both users?

Can you retry the following for a user:

"stsadm -o migrateuser -oldlogin OldDomainName\Username  -newlogin NewDomainName\Username"

If you that does not work, try to add the parameter -ignoresidhistory

Compare the SID and SIDHistory fields.

If it still does not work and the SID values still are not the same after the user is migrated to the new domain, you can try to migrate the user with itself:

"stsadm -o migrateuser -oldlogin NewDomainName\Username  -newlogin NewDomainName\Username -ignoresidhistory"
Try this for a test user.

Comment: Hi TempaC, thanks so much for your super quick reply =]  I'm not a total novice but I don't know how to check the SID values for both users so if you could point me in the right direction that would be amazing - their domain names and user names have changed, so instead of (for example) domaina\firstname it has become domainb\firstname.lastname.  I will try the suggestions you've put and come back in a sec =]

Comment: I've just tried stsadm.exe -o migrateuser -oldlogin domaina\firstname -newlogin domaina\firstname, and it returned the same error - the user does not exist or is not unique

Comment: Get SID of user on SharePoint: "http://blog.bugrapostaci.com/2014/02/05/get-sid-by-powershell-for-sharepoint/" and get Active Directory SID: "https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/2776-powershell-sid-to-user-and-user-to-sid".

Comment: Hi TempaC, the first one led to a 404, but I'll check out the second one and see if I can make it fly =]  Thanks

Comment: First one works as wall when you remove the ":
http://blog.bugrapostaci.com/2014/02/05/get-sid-by-powershell-for-sharepoint/